# Тут нужна аргументация(,) более продвинутая, чем у автора

Tags: пунктуация, синтаксис

Писал ответ на другой вопрос, вспомнил свою старую заморочку.

Вот примеры:

*Тут нужна аргументация(,) более продвинутая, чем у Вас.

Хочу услышать мнение(,) более аргументированное, чем у Вас.*

И т. п.

Вопросы.
~1. Какой частью речи является определение после слова более?
~2. Нужна запятая? Очень хочется иногда поставить - не вижу оснований. В других случаях не очень и хочется, но рука "сама ставит", тоже не очень понимаю почему.

Answer (score 1):

Тут нужна аргументация более продвинутая, чем у Вас. Хочу услышать мнение более аргументированное, чем у Вас.

Но: Хотелось бы услышать другое мнение, более аргументированное, чем у Вас

Более продвинутый, более аргументированный -  согласованные определения в постпозиции не обособляются, так как являются смысловым центром высказывания, на них падает логическое ударение. Но они будут обособляться, если перед определяемым словом уже есть определение.

Примеры:

Но для неверующих нужны были доказательства более очевидные (Н. А. Добролюбов).

Нужны доказательства более прямые (Короленко В. Г.).

Они были обязаны предъявлять доказательства более уважительные (М. Е. Салтыков-Щедрин).

Comment: Согласна, здесь определяемое слово само по себе не выражает нужного смысла и нуждается в определении, которое сливается с ним по смыслу и потому не обособляется. Нужна не просто аргументация, а именно более продвинутая. Продвинутая - причастие перешло в прилагательное в значении "совершенная,более высокого уровня".Хочу услышать не просто мнение, а более аргументированное - прилагательное в значении "достоверное", на это указывает слово "более". Сравнительная степень бывает у качественного прилагательного, а не у причастия.

Comment: @Людмила, не нравится мне этот подход. Сейчас всего не могу сформулировать, вот что что прежде всего всплывает. "Более" можно пристроить почти к любому причастию. Оно от того прилагательным не станет. Более покрашенный забор. Более проваренное мясо. Более постиранная рубаха.  Тут "более" воспринимается как  наречие (=лучше, сильнее). а не как модификатор степени прилагательного.

Comment: А если рассуждать так.  Согласно словарю,  «более»  употребляется в двух случаях:  1) заменяет слово «больше»; 2) используется для образования сравнительной степени прилагательных и наречий. (Больше – это сравнительная степень от «большой» и «много»). В нашем случае слово    «более»  нельзя заменить словом «больше», поэтому  остается образование сравнительной степени.

Comment: И если в приведенных примерах   «более»  относится к признаковой форме, то эта форма обозначает качественный признак, даже если она формально совпадает с причастием, например: вода более нагретая (теплая), но: вода больше (в большей степени)  нагрета (причастие). Получается, что сама форма (более+причастие)  свидетельствует о переходе причастия в прилагательное.